# How to get a Boon From Shiva

Tags: shiva, boon

I have heard that Lord maheswar is very merciful. He grants boon easily. I want to see him please let me know how can i see him. I just want his devotion. Is there any siddhi to please him.Please dont answer like be honest serve other to please  him. Tell any way of you know. Because there are several people who who have got boon in the Ramayan and Mahabharat so why i should not.

Comment: Those people did severe Tapasya and that's how they got the boons. So you too have to do similar Tapasyas. Will you be able to do it?